# Add tags in Company records using infusionsoft API

Tags: infusionsoft

I want to tag company records after I create them using the InfusionSoft API.

How would I do this tag company records via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Company records in Infusionsoft are really just special contact records. You can apply tags to them just like a contact using their ID.

So after you add the company to Infusionsoft via the API, you'll get back the ID of the company. From there, apply a tag to the contact with that ID.

Related Infusionsoft API Docs:

- [Add a Record](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-create-a-record)
- [Apply a Tag](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-add-a-tag-to-a-contact)

Comment: Awesome, @ManishKumar! Thanks for following up! Please 'accept' my answer when you have a moment! :)